# Selenium picture Captha validation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

We upgraded  captcha  in our application to use images instead of  letters
In the previous version I could fill the captcha field with a specific token to pass my the validation. 
Since now there is no such field i need to find an other way to pass the same value for validation. 
Is there a way to do that  using  selenium webdriver ?

I am updating the description

My tests run on  a test enviroment not the actual production site , I already have a String to pass the capcha test. 
Basicly what i need to do is set the parameter thats been posted to the server for captcha validation

Comment: Do you run the automation tests against test environment and/or production?

Comment: Test Emviroment

Answer (score 1):

In your test environment, you need your developers to enable some way of bypassing the captcha.  You need to make sure that is only available in your test environment.  There are a lot of ways of doing it, commonly it is you typing in a specific string that is recognized by the system to bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, talk with the developers. They could quickly develop something like this:

If test environment, than accept a specific input oft the captcha; else accept only the real solution of the captcha.

In the most cases exist a config file for things like that.

Keep in mind, that captchas exist to prevent automation. So I think you has no other option.